# rolling regression of each window with groupby

Tags: r

I have a monthly data for each group, and I want to do regression for each group, and window is 2 years and get slope.

I tried several methods

1. I tried to use for loop and filter 2-year data each time, then do lm

> ```
> df$Year =year(df$date)
> df1<-purrr::map_df(min(df$Year):(max(df$Year) - 2), function(i) {
>              df %>%
>               filter(Year%in% c(i,i+1)) %>%
>               group_by(group)%>%
>     do(lm = lm(R ~ M, data = .,na.action=na.exclude)) %>%
>       mutate(lm_b0 = summary(lm)$coeff[1],
>              lm_b1 = summary(lm)$coeff[2])%>%
>     ungroup()
>   })
> ```

get the error:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)
> :    0 (non-NA) cases

2. then I tried to define a function slope, but result df1, column "slope" is all NA

> ```
> slope <- . %>% { cov(.[, 2], .[, 1]) / var(.[, 2])}
> df1<-df %>%
>        group_by(group,Year) %>%
>        mutate(slope = rollapplyr(cbind(R, M), 2, slope, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)) %>%ungroup()
> ```

3. and I found roll_lm method:

> ```
> library(roll)
> df1<-df%>%
>   group_by(group,Year)%>%
>   roll_lm(MKT,RET,2)
> ```

get the error:

> Error in roll_lm(., M, R, 5) : object 'M' not found

4.The I tried this, but result is all NA

```
df1<-df%>%
  group_by(group,Year)%>%
  do(data.frame(., rolling_coef = rollapplyr(data = ., width = 2, FUN = function(df_) {
    mod = lm(R ~ M, data = .)
    return(coef(mod)[2])
  }, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)))
```

I also tried use `beta` directly, it could work, but seems beta is for nonnegative numeric variable, my M and R have negative value.

Could someone give me some ideas? Thank you!

My dataset is similar to this:
[image]

and I want the result be: (2002: use previous two-year monthly data do regression and find slope)
[image]

Comment: please provide a reprex

Comment: sorry. I did not use reprex before. And it always gets error. I made a sample code and data file in github. https://github.com/lingqi-w/testing.git

Comment: @ling They mean a minimal reproducible example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038

Comment: `set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
    group = sample(letters[1:4], 500, replace = TRUE),
    date= sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2003/01/01'),by="m"), 500, replace = TRUE),
    R=sample(runif(20),500,replace = TRUE),
    M=sample(runif(10),500,replace = TRUE)
)` Thank you @jay.sf It is really helpful. I created a sample dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want this.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(0:6, function(y) 
  do.call(rbind, by(d, d$g, function(g) {
    b <- unname(lm(R ~ M, g[substr(g$t, 1, 4) %in% (2000:2001 + y), ])$coe)
    data.frame(group=g$g[[1]], date=2002 + y, b0=b[1], b1=b[2])
  }))
  ))
res
#    group date          b0          b1
# a      a 2002  0.11269711  0.50982041
# b      b 2002 -0.18383806  0.77395640
# a1     a 2003 -0.04830032  0.38158442
# b1     b 2003  0.05165555 -0.02668866
# a2     a 2004  0.04793637 -0.15872739
# b2     b 2004  0.27075037 -0.28167401
# a3     a 2005 -0.17276432 -0.41435303
# b3     b 2005  0.21656421 -0.22557376
# a4     a 2006 -0.29442007  0.45387752
# b4     b 2006 -0.02507721 -0.09527979
# a5     a 2007 -0.11417319  0.54403146
# b5     b 2007 -0.34265074 -0.33346084
# a6     a 2008 -0.13838241  0.33467995
# b6     b 2008 -0.02713155  0.25299279
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
d <- expand.grid(g=letters[1:2], t=seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length.out=96, by="m"),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
d <- transform(d, R=round(rnorm(nrow(d)), 2), M=round(rnorm(nrow(d))/2, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried to get the data, and get the error:  `Error in stringsAsFactors && is.character(x) : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'.  ` so I try to apply this method in my dataset: using `res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(0:6, function(y) 
  do.call(rbind, by(df, df$group, function(group) {
    b <- unname(lm(R ~ M, group[substr(group$Year, 1, 4) %in% (2000:2001 + y), ])$coe)
    data.frame(group=group$group[[1]], date=2002 + y, b0=b[1], b1=b[2])
  }))
  ))` I think I misunderstand the structure of the code?

Comment: @ling Where you put `Year` you should put the whole date, e.g. `2000/1/1`. Probably you get some of my data as factor. Which R version are you running (type `version`)?

Comment: My version is version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22), and Mac. Oh, I see, the `stringAsFactors` could be replace by `replace = TRUE`. Then it could run